# Чем открыть флеш-сайт, кроме WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms

Чем открывать флеш-сайт, кроме WebBrowser?

И как это сделать

---

**UPD**

пробовал Awesomium, но там почему-то не работает аппаратное ускорение, всё тормозит. Да и размер проекта становится 40 мб... я думал может есть какое-то другое решение, сам флеш-плеер какой-то голый, но он же не может открыть сайт? или может... если он полностью на флеше

Comment: Какая цель? Отобразить пользователю? Вытащить данные?

Comment: отобразить пользователю

Comment: Видеоплеером можно попробовать :) GOM Player умеет интерактивные swf.

Comment: как это сделать) я новичок, сложно это всё самому копать... сутки могут уйти

Comment: ну возьмите другой движок, во [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/170015/) целая статья как это сделать

Comment: @rdorn пробовал Awesomium, но там почему-то не работает аппаратное ускорение, всё тормозит. Да и размер проекта становится 40 мб... я думал может есть какое-то другое решение, сам флеш-плеер какой-то голый, но он же не может открыть сайт? или может... если он полностью на флеше....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через COM компонент Shockwave Flash Object

```
axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, "http://site.com/flash.swf");   // флеш-объект в сети
axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = @"C:\holdthelinegame.swf";           // локальный файл
```

(!) Флеш-объект в сети обязательно должен быть прямой ссылкой на .swf файл.
 Узнать прямую ссылку можно покопавшись в исходном тексте страницы сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

> пробовал Awesomium, но там почему-то не работает аппаратное ускорение,
>   всё тормозит.

А документацию и гугл изучали? Где-то должно включаться, еще можно попробовать другой плагин, другую версию.

> Да и размер проекта становится 40 мб...

Это много?

> сам флеш-плеер какой-то голый, но он же не может открыть сайт? или
>   может... если он полностью на флеше....

SWF точно может открыть. Пробуйте скачать SWF и открывать...

Comment: гуглил, код вставлял - не включается все равно. для моей простенькой программки 40 мб многовато, но это так, второй вопрос, мне бы чтоб работало главное... а как другую версию плагина поставить? это в систему ставить? в системе нормальный стоит, там все работает. или в самом  Awesomium?